# Getting the date from 30 days ago and converting to iso8601 format

Tags: php, date, datetime, amazon-mws

I am trying to get the date from 30 days ago and make sure it is in iso8601 format for use in Amazon MWS this is what I have tried, it works to a point and it looks as thought it is in the right format but amazon still says its not correct!

```
$tester = date("c");
$tester = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($tester . ' -30 days'));
$datetime = urlencode($tester);
echo $datetime;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `"c"`:

```
$tester = date('c', strtotime('-30 days'));
// if current  date is: 2018-05-02T13:53:24+05:00
// the result would be: 2018-04-02T13:53:24+05:00
```

Having said that, I suggest switching to [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = new DateTime();               // create date for current date
$date->sub(new DateInterval("P30D")); // subtract 30 days
echo $date->format("c");              // 2018-04-02T13:57:54+05:00
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks turns out it was a keystroke error!